# Parse PFCloud.callInBackground completion block never called i.e no response received

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have defined a function in the Parse Cloud Code called "relatedWords". When I try call this function in my iOS app, the completion block/closure is never called i.e no response is received.

I've tested the function in the Parse API Console and it is working fine there, so I know it's not an issue with the cloud code.

Any ideas on what the issue is?

My swift code:

```
func fetchRelatedKeyWordsForWord(word: String)
{
    PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("relatedWords", withParameters: ["hashtag": word]) { (response, error) -> Void in
        //This is never called
        print(response)
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Snippet of the cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("relatedWords", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var hashtag = request.params.hashtag;
  ...
  ...
  //Run a query
  var query = new Parse.Query(parseClassName);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      if (results.length != 0) {
         console.log("Found Objects! Returning Objects");
         response.success(results);
         return;
      }
```

Edit:
I figured out the problem. It was silly mistake by me. The reason the cloud code was not getting called is that I had not setup parse in my ApplicationDidFinishLaunching i.e I did not call `Parse.setApplicationId("...", clientKey: "...")`

Comment: what happens in the else case?

Comment: It will perform a whole bunch of functions and eventually return response.success or response.failure. But for the case that I am testing, it will not go to the else case

Comment: I've tried testing it by putting `response.success("success")` on the first line on the function. I still don't receive the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. It was silly mistake by me. The reason the cloud code was not getting called is that I had not setup parse in my ApplicationDidFinishLaunching i.e I did not call `Parse.setApplicationId("...", clientKey: "...")`

Answer (score -2):

I figured out the problem. 
you can use other server, other vise pay money on parse and solve the problem.